# Changing images onClick()

Tags: java, android, image

I'm building an android app and I need some advices (I am totally new to java and I've been reading [this](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html)), I have one button and one image, I need to change the image each time the button is pressed.
It is a button that looks like stones and the image is a bowl, I need that each time when the stone button is pressed that the bowl has one more stone in it (I have images of the bowl with 1, 2, 3, ... stones in it).
How would I do that? I'm not necessarly asking for the code, just the way I should do it.

Comment: That's the problem I don't really know how to beggin, for nowI only have the stone button and the bowl but that's about it. I'm just asking for advices on how to proceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take your bowl images in Array

```
int[] Img_array={R.drawable.bowl1,R.drawable.bowl2,......}
```

& use its position in Onclick event of button

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
             Public int counter=0;
             Button button;
             ImageView imageview;
             int[] Img_array={R.drawable.bowl1,R.drawable.bowl2};

                @Override
             public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.main);
              button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.MyButton);
              imageview=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.MyImageView);
               button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                 imageview.setBackgroundResource(Img_array[counter]);
                                      Counter++;
                                 if(counter==Img_array.length())
                                  {
                                        Counter=0;
                                   }


                                      }
                      });
           }
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks, as I Said I'm a total **begginer** when it comes to java, so where shall I put this code? (sorry for asking in such details... :/ )

Comment: Check my edited answer.you can put this whole code in your Activity in which you want this functionality

Comment: so for exemple in the mainactivity.java?

Comment: ok so I pasted the above code, modified the necessary fields but I still have two errors: on the 'int[] Img_array={R.drawable.bowl0,R.drawable.bowl1}' line where it says: Syntax error, insert ";" to complete FieldDeclaration and on the 'imageview=(Imageview))findViewById(R.id.whiteBowl);' line where it says Multiple markers at this line
 - Imageview cannot be resolved to a type
 - Syntax error on token ")", delete this 
  token
 - Imageview cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: its minor errors. put ; at the end of line 'int[] Img_array={R.drawable.bowl0,R.drawable.bowl1}'  & remove ) from 'imageview=(Imageview))findViewById(R.id.whiteBowl);'  check my edited answer

Comment: I  have one last error on the imageview line: Multiple markers at this line
 - Imageview cannot be resolved to a 
  type
 - Imageview cannot be resolved to a 
  type

Comment: yes. check your imageview=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.MyImageView);line..replace it... as you have (Imageview).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
        Button stoneButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.stoneButton);
        ImageView bowlImageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.bowlImageView);;

         mCount=0;

        ArrayList<Integer> yourImages = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        yourImages.add(R.drawable.image1);
        yourImages.add(R.drawable.image2);
        yourImages.add(R.drawable.image3);


        stoneButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(mCount<yourImages.size())
                {
                bowlImageView.setImageResource(yourImages.get(mCount));
                mCount++;
                }

            }
        });
```

Make Sure that you check the size in `onClick` other wise it will crash.

Also it is better to use  `setImageResource` than `setBackgroundResource` in an `ImageView`